# What is the net ionic equation for the reaction between Ba(OH)2 and H2SO4?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I know its either:

1.) Ba + SO4 = BaSO4

2.) Ba + 2OH + 2H + SO4 = BaSO4 + 2H2O

But can someone explain why water is or isn't part of the net ionic?

Comment: There is no such thing as SO4, OH in chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

The reaction between $\ce{Ba(OH)2, H2SO4}$ is known as acid-base neutralisation, as $\ce{Ba(OH)2}$ is a relatively strong base and $\ce{H2SO4}$ the strong acid.

The molecular reaction is given as,

$$\ce{Ba(OH)2 + H2SO4 -> BaSO4 (s) + 2H2O}$$

> Before moving to net-ionic reaction, let's see the reaction of $\ce{BaCl2, Na2SO4}$ **[1]**:
>
> $$\ce{BaCl2 + Na2SO4 -> BaSO4 (s) + 2NaCl}$$
>
> So, breaking up into ions, we see:
>
> $$\ce{Ba^{2+} + 2Cl- + 2Na^{+} + SO4^{2-} -> BaSO4 (s) + 2Na^{+} + 2Cl^{-}}$$
>
> $\ce{Na^{+}, Cl^{-}}$ remains completely dissociated in the aqueous solution as they're salts of strong acid and strong base (i.e., they're strong electrolytes). Hence, $\ce{Na^{+}, Cl^{-}}$ are spectator ions as they don't participate in ionic reaction. Let's cancel them out, and we get the net ionic reaction:
>
> $$\ce{Ba^{2+} + SO4^{2-} -> BaSO4 (s)}$$

Now, let's see the reaction given in the question. In this, $\ce{BaSO4}$ precipitates out, so $\ce{Ba^{2+}, SO4^{2-}}$ can't be spectator ions. Also, H2O has a very low dissociation contant ($\ce{K_W = 10^{-14}}$, at 25°C), so it can't dissociate into ions. Hence, $\ce{H+, OH-}$ are too not the spectator ion. Therefore, this reaction has no spectator ion and hence **${H_2O}$ will be included in the ionic reaction**, which is given as:

$$\ce{Ba^{2+} + 2OH- + 2H+ + SO4^{2-} -> BaSO4 (s) + 2H2O(l)}$$

---

Another example:

**[1]:** [Complete ionic and net ionic equations, Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/chemical-reactions-stoichiome/types-of-chemical-reactions/a/complete-ionic-and-net-ionic-equations)

<sup>Note: As mentioned by andselisk in comments, $\ce{BaSO4 (s)}$ is the recommended way to write the precipitate, as per IUPAC. Old school symbol for precipitate was "↓".</sup>

Comment: Your highlighted equations have some erroneous in ions (e.g., $\ce{Ba^2+ + 2 Cl- -> BaSO4}$). Please revisit and correct.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne: Many thanks for pointing out. I've corrected them now.

Comment: "(↓)" is not a standardized notation and it never was. "↓" is an obsolete symbol to denote solid state; consider replacing it with the currently recommended "(s)" notation. This would also make the reactions look coherent since you are already denoting liquid state of aggregation this way. Further on the nitpicking side, it might be worth mentioning $K_\mathrm{w} = \pu{1E-14}$ at 25 °C only, in order not to give a student a false sense that it is some fundamental constant (also, note the typography of "$K_\mathrm{w}$").

Comment: @RahulVerma Exactly, like "Cu(s)". Please see Section 2.10.1 (vi), p. 54 of IUPAC "Green Book" ([PDF](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/IUPAC-GB3-2012-2ndPrinting-PDFsearchable.pdf#page=68)). Alternatively, you can consult [ACS Guide to Scholarly Communication](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/book/10.1021/acsguide) if you have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't seem to understand the concepts let's break this down more. Rahul's answer is correct, but let's go into more detail. Consider dissolving barium chloride, equation 1, and sodium sulfate,equation 2, in separate solutions. (*Note that it is important to show the charge on ions!*)

$$\ce{BaCl2(s) ->[aq] Ba^{2+}(aq) + 2Cl-(aq)}\tag{1}$$
$$\ce{Na2SO4(s) ->[aq] 2Na^{+}(aq) + SO4^{2-}(aq)}\tag{2}$$

Now if the two ionic solutions are mixed the reaction is:
$$\ce{Ba^{2+}(aq) + 2Cl-(aq) + 2Na^{+}(aq) + SO4^{2-}(aq) <=> BaSO4(s) + 2Na^{+}(aq) +  2Cl-(aq)}\tag{3}$$

- (s) means that the reactant is a solid, or that the product is a precipitate.
- (aq) means that the molecule or ion is dissolved in water. Often this it is assumed that the context is an aqueous solution and the designation is just left off.

Since the sodium ions and the chloride ions appear on both sides of the equation they are often canceled out as spectator ions. So for a reaction you might see an equation like equation (4). Typically one would assume that for equation 4 that the $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions came from some unspecified soluble salts, and that the reaction was happening in water.

$$\ce{Ba^{2+} + SO4^{2-} <=> BaSO4(s)}\tag{4}$$

Another way to specify reaction conditions would be to put such specifications over the reaction arrows. Such as using $\ce{ ->[CH3OH]}$ to indicate that the reaction is happening in methanol.